# Help on how to let a user change his password after authentication

Tags: php, mysql

When a user forgets his password, there is an email sent to his email account with a link and token (unique) to resetpassword.php

When the authentication is correct then he is able to change the password. My question is how can this happen? 
The quick and easy way is to email him a new password and let him change it through his CP, but is this a good user-experience?

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT member_id FROM members WHERE forgotpass='$token'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {

            WHAT GOES HERE?
    }
    else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
```

Comment: Usually you'd use the token's validity to show a form which lets the user enter a new PW, and THEN update their record. It's user-unfriendly to force them to fill out the new pw and only THEN tell them at the token is invalid.

Comment: @Marc B : This is true but this is not working like the way you say. At first it checks for the token validation and then there is `what goes here?`

Comment: then it'd be `include('newpasswordform.php')` to display the form. Have that form embed the token in a hidden field, so it can be double-checked when the new password is submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WHAT GOES HERE?

there should be something like

```
echo 'Your password was mailed to you';
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET password = '".$random_hashed_string."' WHERE forgotpass='$token'");
mail($to, $subject, $message." password:".$random_hashed_string, "From: support@support.com");
```

Comment: Is the answer to my updated question... Is emailing a new generated password and letting him to change it through his control panel is good user experience ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a form to allow the user to select a new password. The form's action will update the database user record's password field. This will probably be a separate process, but your `WHAT GOES HERE?` will be an HTML form.